# libgdx box2d - What is the proper way of syncing body and texture?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, box2d

**Question** What is the proper way of syncing  body and texture? Should I make body follows sprite position or vice-versa? Below is the options I've created.

- **Option 1:** The `Body` follows the `Texture/Sprite` position.

  `Body` - `Texture`

  ```
  // Initialize position
  bodyDef.position.set(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
  Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

  // Update position
  body.setTransform(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
  ```
- **Option 2:** The `Texture/Sprite` follows `Body` position.

  `Texture` - `Body`

  ```
  Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
  // Initialize and Update position
  Vector2 bodyPos = body.getPosition();
  sprite.setPosition(bodyPos.x, bodyPos.y);
  sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle());
  ```

Comment: I like the analogy I read somewhere once saying "think of your bodies as moving billboards that you attach your image(s) to". So use the box2d step to move all the bodies based on collisions and actual physics and then draw your sprites "on the billboards" wherever they are (where box2d is telling you the bodies are located).

Comment: It should definitely be option 2 because setting the position directly on each frame defeats the purpose of a physics engine.